# How to redirect the user to detail page after saving a new pod item/record in Pods / Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, hook, podscms

After saving a new pod item, I want to redirect the user to the detail page of the newly created record. How can I achieve this?

I tried using post_save hooks but it didn't work. I used the following code:

```
function redirect_to_detail($data, $is_new_item) {
  $pod_type = $data['params']['pod'];
  $id = $data['params']['id'];
  wp_redirect( home_url() . "/{$pod_type}/{$id}" ); exit;
}

add_filter('pods_api_post_save_pod_item', 'redirect_to_detail', 10, 2);
```

The pod item is created by a shortcode like this:

```
[pods name="egitim" form="1" fields="name, salon" label="Kaydet"]
```

Comment: Have you added some kind of `die('filter worked')` test to your function to make sure the `pods_api_post_save_pod_item` filter is hooking when you expect it to?

Comment: Thank you for this warning. Indeed, the filter is not hooking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

`[pods name="egitim" form="1" fields="name, salon" label="Kaydet" thank_you="/egitim/X_ID_X/"]`

Comment: But the item is going to be created newly. So it doesn't have any id at the time the shortcode is processed.

Comment: X_ID_X is a placeholder, Pods will swap it out with the real ID automatically during the redirect.

Answer (score 0):

pods_api_post_save_pod_item is an action not a filter, so use add_action

Comment: You could add additional information such as a link to the docs about that action here: https://docs.pods.io/code/action-reference/pods_api_post_save_item/